# VS 2022 switch statement auto-fill not available

Tags: visual-studio, switch-statement

I use Visual Studio Community on a Mac for Unity development and have just updated from 2019 to 2022, all appears well except for switch statements. It used to be when using enums with switch statements I had the option to auto-fill the switch block with a case statement for each enum value but I no longer have the option in VS 2022.

I've tried Googling but not seeing a mention of the issue, any ideas on how to remedy this?

Many thanks

Comment: You can install a resharper

Comment: @dexiang if it's free I'll take it! I used to use Idea a lot and that had some nice features.

Comment: I was frustrated that feature was removed, but it is still functional. I have switched on several options via Options -> Editor and restarted VS. Unfortunately I am not sure which option is responsible for this feature.

Comment: @walter33 I've been using VS 2022 with Unity for a while now and I'm seriously considering going back to VS 2019. The QoL improvements are good but it just doesn't play well with Unity and I think Unity is to blame here. VS 2019 also has problems but they're worse with 2022. One major problem VS has is its memory usage. I have to restart it every day or two as it eats memory and never releases it leading to long stalls and high CPU usage. I need to have multiple VS instances open which just makes things all the more painful.

Comment: @cerestorm I have very similar experience. I am experimenting with MAUI so I am trying to install latest VS Preview versions together with C#,  but it is frustrating that VS consumes high CPU. Each VS brings some new "troubles". At the same time I am developing Java application using IDEA and this is better and better experience with each version.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the caret on your "switch" keyword and use the default [Ctrl+;] shortcut for 'Quick Actions and Refactoring' ...

Then choose [Add missing cases].

Tadaaa.